# Increase distance between axis line and plot lines on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I increase the distance between the `axis.line.y` below and the blue `geom_hline` below? I want a gap between the two, I don't want them kissing as shown on the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 25, color = "blue") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "black"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but try it.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = min(cty), y = 25, 
                   xend = max(cty), yend = 25), 
               data = mpg) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "black"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q112f.png]

Comment: This could work, but as I look at the output the line visually _seems_ too short. I think I'd rather pad the space between the current `geom_hline()` and the `axis.line.y()`. Thank you though.

Comment: yup, its short. Maybe you could do `x = 0.9*min(cty)` or any factor instead of 0.9 but you would have to change it according to each graph in order to fit the gap that you are looking for.    How are you padding the space between those lines?

Comment: @JasonHunter we could change *xend* to infinity to make it look "long": `xend = Inf`.